# Showing $\Bbb{Z}*\Bbb{Z}\cong F_2$ using universal properties

Tags: algebraic-topology, universal-property

I am just a beginner in Algebraic Topology, and I need to show $\Bbb{Z}*\Bbb{Z}\cong F_2$, where $F_2$ is the free group on two generators, using universal properties.

Using simple constructions, I see both $F_2$ and $\Bbb{Z}*\Bbb{Z}$ look like the collection of all words of the form $\{a^{\alpha_1}\cdot b^{\beta_1}\cdot a^{\alpha_2}\cdot b^{\beta_2}\dots a^{\alpha_n}\cdot b^{\beta_n}|\alpha_i,\beta_i\in\Bbb{Z}\}$.

But I need to prove by universal properties, so first I will list the relevant ones:

**The universal property of $\Bbb{Z}*\Bbb{Z}$:**

There are two inclusions $i:\Bbb{Z}\rightarrow\Bbb{Z}*\Bbb{Z}$ and $j:\Bbb{Z}\rightarrow\Bbb{Z}*\Bbb{Z}$, and for any group $G$ with two homomorphisms $\phi:\Bbb{Z}\rightarrow G$ and $\psi:\Bbb{Z}\rightarrow G$ there is a unique homomorphism $\eta:\Bbb{Z}*\Bbb{Z}\rightarrow G$ such that $\eta\circ i=\phi$ and $\eta\circ j=\psi$.

**The universal property of $F_2$:**

Given a set of two elements $S=\{a,b\}$, $F_2$ is the free group on $S$, if it has a mapping $i:S\rightarrow F_2$ and for any group $G$ with a mapping $\phi:S\rightarrow G$ there is a unique homomorphism $\psi:F_2\rightarrow G$ such that $\psi\circ i=\phi$.

Now, I have no idea how to proceed. How are proofs by universal properties go about?

Comment: If $S$ is a set, then it doesn't make sense for $i:S \to F_2$ to be a homomorphism.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Sorry, my bad. It is just a mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to show that $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies the universal property of $F_2$.

$\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ satisfies the universal property of $F_2$.

Let $S=\{a,b\}$ define $i(a)=1_{\mathbb{Z}_1}$ and $i(b)=1_{\mathbb{Z}_2}$, for any morphism $f:S\rightarrow G$, you can define $f_1:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow G$ such that $f_1(n)=f(a)^n$ and $f_2(n)=f(b)^n$, the universal properties of $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ implies the existence of a morphism of group $h:\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow G$ such that $h(n*0)=f(a)^n$ and $h(0*m)=f(b)^m$, in particular $h(i(a))=f(a)$ and $h(i(b))=f(b)$.

This implies that $F_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ are isomorphic.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it answers my question. Just one point: how do you define $1*0$ and such? I understand $*$ as used in a free product of groups, not on single elements.

Comment: In the free group generated by $G_1$ and $G_2$, you can write reduced form of elements as $g_1*g_2...g_n$, see the book of Magnus, Karrass and Solitar.

Comment: @TsemoAristide writing $*$ between elements (as in $1 * 0$) doesn't seem to be standard notation for the free product.  It's not clear how one should interpret it in such a way that $1 * 0$ and $0 * 1$ denote the two generators.  For instance, perhaps you denote $(1 * 0)*(0*1) = (1 * 1)$, but how would you denote the distinct element $(0*1)*(1*0)$?

Comment: You don't have relations in a free group, I should have written $1_{\mathbb{Z}_1}$ for the first copy of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

The universal property of free groups is really an explicit version of the statement that the free group functor $F: \mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Grp}$ is left-adjoint to the forgetful functor $U: \mathbf{Grp} \to \mathbf{Set}$.

Now the coproduct in the category of sets is the disjoint union, whereas the coproduct in the category of groups is the free product.
Using the fact that left-adjoint functors commute with colimits, we have:
$F(\{a,b\}) = F(\{a\} \coprod \{b\}) \cong F(\{a\}) * F(\{a\}) \cong \mathbb Z * \mathbb Z$. Here we used the obvious fact that $\mathbb Z$ is the free group on one generator.

This proof may too high-level for you right now, depending on your background, but it has the nice property that it generalizes easily to sets of any size and other categories with free objects.

Comment: It is indeed too high-level for me now, but I might come back to it later. Thanks!